# Group by column value and set it as index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by

I have a dataframe `df1` that looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,5,4,8,9,0,7,6],
                   'B':['a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k'],
                   'C':['XX','XX','XX','YY','YY','WW','ZZ','ZZ']})
```

My goal is to group the elements according to the values contained in column `C`so that rows having the same value, have the same index (which must contain the value stored in `C`). Therefore the output should be like this:

```
    A  B   
XX  0  a  
    5  s  
    4  d  
YY  8  f  
    9  g  
WW  0  h  
ZZ  7  j  
    6  k
```

I tried to use the command `df.groupby('C')` but it returns the following object:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000001A9D4860>
```

Can you suggest me an elegant and smart way to achieve my goal?

Note: I think my question is somehow related to multi-indexing

Comment: You mean `df1.set_index('C')`?

Comment: it's similar but does not fit to my problem because it would assign and index to each element while what I would like to do is different... I would like to have an index to access the content of the dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
df2 = df1.set_index('C')
print (df2)
    A  B
C       
XX  0  a
XX  5  s
XX  4  d
YY  8  f
YY  9  g
WW  0  h
ZZ  7  j
ZZ  6  k

print (df2.loc['XX'])
    A  B
C       
XX  0  a
XX  5  s
XX  4  d
```

If need `MultiIndex` from columns `C` and `A`:

```
df3 = df1.set_index(['C', 'A'])
print (df3)
      B
C  A   
XX 0  a
   5  s
   4  d
YY 8  f
   9  g
WW 0  h
ZZ 7  j
   6  k

print (df3.loc['XX'])
   B
A   
0  a
5  s
4  d
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `pivot_table` i.e

```
pd.pivot_table(df1, values='A', index=['C','B'])
```

Output :

```
      A
C  B   
WW h  0
XX a  0
   d  4
   s  5
YY f  8
   g  9
ZZ j  7
   k  6
```